# How to build ng-admin?

Tags: ng-admin

I have to use functions which are only in Master yet (like `onSubmitSuccess` or `onSubmitError`) and I couldn't find information on how to build ng-admin from source. I'm not proficient in JS tools, please give me example.

Comment: I managed to build it with `make build`, but then the app doesn't work at all, and sadly without any errors.